# Sending message to object that is member of array

Tags: objective-c

Really hoping someone can help me sort out why sending objects that are members of an array seems to be the hardest thing in the world in Obj-C.

Here's the setup: I have a car class. Car has two member objects, engine and tire (of which there are four). Then I have an NSArray (also a member of car) initialized to hold the tire objects. I did this because I cannot figure out how to write or synthesize getter methods for just declaring like Tire *tires[4] (so I have to use NSArray and use objectAtIndex.

Here is the car class:

```
#import "Tire.h"
#import "Engine.h"

@interface Car : NSObject
{
    Engine *engine;
    Tire *tire1;
    Tire *tire2;
    Tire *tire3;
    Tire *tire4;
    NSArray *tirearray;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) id engine;
@property (nonatomic, copy) id tire;
@property (nonatomic, copy) id tirearray;

@implementation Car

@synthesize engine;
@synthesize tire;
@synthesize tirearray;

- (void) print {

    NSLog(@"%@", engine);

}

- (id) init {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        engine = [Engine new];
        tire1 = [[tire alloc] init];
        tire2 = [[tire alloc] init];
        tire3 = [[tire alloc] init];
        tire4 = [[tire alloc] init];
        tirearray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: tire1, tire2, tire3, tire4, nil];
    }

    return (self);

}
```

Then main:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Car *car = [[Car alloc] init];

    [[car.tirearray objectAtIndex:0] setPressure: 32];


    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is figure out how to send messages to the objects in the array! That's all I want to do. The above code builds, but returns uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)' !!!

Just so you know, pressure is just a member variable of the tire class, and the getter methods have been synthesized.

Then I want to print something to the console like "The pressure of tire X is X PSI".

This is driving me nuts! This should be simple! AHHHH.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
        tire1 = [[tire alloc] init];
```

should be

```
        tire1 = [[Tire alloc] init];
```

Who told you to declare a property as an `id`? That's a very, very, very bad practice and you should stop it now. Right now.

If you bought a textbook which says so, please just burn it to ashes now.

By declaring your property

```
 @property (nonatomic, copy) Tire* tire;
```

the compiler warn you at

```
        tire1 = [[tire alloc] init];
```

saying that `tire` doesn't respond to `alloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man. I feel so silly. I didn't initialize the array at all! I need to alloc then initialize with initWithObjects. Haha. Oops.

Comment: 1. Don't write an answer, amend the question.  2. What is the error you now get and where?

Comment: Thanks. I just started using StackOverflow and didn't quite get how to use it. I will keep that in mind! "Answer" is different from comment. Got it :P